# Azure ASP.NET location element in web.config

Tags: asp.net, azure

Does the web.config for a ASP.NET project function differently when run in the Azure emulator?

By default azure is allowing my Images folder to be served with prior login, even with the following in my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx"
         name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
         cookieless="UseCookies"
         timeout="30"
         path="/"
         slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>    
</authorization>
```

There is no <location> tag in my web.config. When running the ASP project alone under IIS, nothing gets served, but when running under the Azure emulator images still get served.

Answer (score 0):

Did you force refresh your browser (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) or try different browsers? Browsers like to cache images so they may still not be served up in the emulator - they are likely cached versions.

Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see if the image requests are truly being served up.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re allowing anonymous access to the site. Then even if a user is not authenticated, he can still access the pages in your web site.

> > when running under the Azure emulator images still get served.

The Windows Azure emulator behavior is correct. If you want to deny anonymous access, please configure the authorization tag as:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>    
</authorization>
```

to see whether it helps.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.